# Archiving Records With the same status

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a parent table p and child table c.

```
p
id varchar2(10),
status  varchar2(10),
add_date date
```

```
c
id  varchar2(10),
p_id varchar2(10),(foreign key to p)
status varchar2(10)
add_date date
```

For instance, P record has status of 'COMPLETE'
p_id can have multiple records in c.
I want to query only the records for c
where all the p_id entries have a status of 'COMPLETE'

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, what do YOU mean by "archiving" and what does that have to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: are you sure about to hold `status` column with the similar content for both tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `group by` as following:

```
Select p.id
From table_p p join table_c c
on p.id = c.p_id
Where p.status = 'complete'
Group by p.id
Having count(1) = sum(case when c.status = 'COMPLETE' then 1 end);
```

Cheers!!